# How to use non-ASCII strings in email Subject:, To: etc in PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail

Please tell me, I send using curl php email (gmail api). Content-Type is message/rfc822.
How can I use Cyrillic in the Subject of an email when sending. In the body of the letter Cyrillic is displayed normally, in the subject of the letter it is displayed as symbols. ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ.

```
$access_token = "***";

$message = "To: ".addslashes($_POST['to'])."\r\nSubject: ".addslashes($_POST['subject'])."\r\n\r\n".addslashes($_POST['message']);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token, 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: message/rfc822; charset=utf-8'));    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP person but look for support for MIME RFC2047 encoding. In very brief, `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0L/RgNC40LLQtdGCCg==?=`

Comment: Looking up the meaning of `addslashes` I'm almost certain that is the wrong thing to do here. Use RFC2047 instead, not in addition to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the standard php function:

```
mb_encode_mimeheader($_POST['subject'], "UTF-8");
```